# Unpack dictionary in column in SQL table

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table `my_table` looking like below:

```
id        name             dict
1         Andy             [{'age':34, 'gender':male, 'phone':xxx}]
2         Belle            [{'age':32, 'gender':female, 'phone':xxx}]
```

How do I `SELECT` from this table and create new columns at the same time so that I receive:

```
id     name        age       gender         phone
1      Andy        34        male           xxx
2      Belle       32        female         xxxx
```

What is a generic solution that does not require to know the details of the dictionary? i.e., not know the exact keys and values in the column `dict`?

Comment: What data type is this "dictionary" column? Why isn't that a valid JSON value, which would make things a lot easier.

Comment: It's JSON. But how do I apply a solution without know the inner content of the JSON? The solution suggested by @nbk requires dealing with all the keys one by one.

Comment: The sample data is not valid JSON. But there is no way you can get a dynamic list of columns like that. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and types of all columns of a query must be known to the database before it starts retrieving data. You can't have a query that returns 2 columns today and 10 columns tomorrow on the same table.

Comment: The original question is what I saw in the dataset I work with. I checked with the original raw dataset, and I have edited the question to reflect exactly how that original dataset looks like. Hope this can lead to a solution?